# In Java, is it necessary to call unlock after a InterruptedException, or should unlock be avoided?

Tags: java, locking, mutex

In the following code snippet, I'm not sure whether to set locked to false after the InterruptedException:

```
private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

void foo() {
    final long timeout = 30;
    boolean locked = false;
    try {
        locked = lock.tryLock(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Do time consuming work that might be interrupted
        // ...
        // ...
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        locked = false;  // Is this correct????
    } finally {
        if( locked) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I omitted the "time consuming work that might be interrupted" from my original example, so it looked like I was asking about the usage of tryLock rather than about what happens in the case of thread interruption.  So what if the lock is granted, then the thread is interrupted. Does that automatically release the lock, or does it have to occur in the `finally` clause?

Edit2: It seems I had a misunderstanding of thread interruption in Java.  If `Thread.interrupt()` was called on this thread, then `Thread.interrupted()` would be true, rather than a `InterruptedException` being raised, unless the following code were included:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

This would raise the ambiguous InterruptedException that I was concerned about.  So it looks like the lesson here is that if you're using trylock(timeout), then don't throw an InterruptedException.

Comment: `locked = false;` in the catch block is redundant.

Comment: See my edit, in which the lock is achieved, but the thread interrupted.

Comment: If the code in Edit2 that throws an InterruptedException in the case of thread interruption were included, then setting locked = false in the catch block would be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't locked the lock successfully, then you shouldn't unlock it.

Comment: That seems correct.  I was thinking that if the thread were interrupted after the lock was obtained then a InterruptedException would occur.  But such is not the case.